# C# SQL database access

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, visual-studio, phpmyadmin

I need your help.  I'm trying to get into servers on my own. I was searching yesterday about it a bit, I saw one code here and also tried one from a YT video. Not exactly sure what I'm doing. I've created an online SQL database on this page https://remotemysql.com/. I've created a database and table and manually assigned some values for further testing.  Then I started to look for some code to open the database

```html
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System;

namespace SQLTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello world"); //for testing
            string server = "Momoos-PC";
            string database = "Score";
            string uid = "iqWUaqal5x";
            string password = "Q4tcOaJXdW";
            string connectionString;
            connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + "; PORT = 3306 ;" + "DATABASE=" + database + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";";
            MySqlConnection mycon = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
            mycon.Open(); //error
            Console.WriteLine("Connection Open  !");
            mycon.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

So I understand that there is a need for some connection string but I'm not sure how it should look like or what library to use (mysqlconnection/sqlconnection).

string server - I'm not sure what to write here but when I'm in the PHPmyAdmin it says Server: localhost, But it shouldn't be because it's online no? So I wrote the localhost as my PC's name. Idk.

Then there is a string database. Don't know if they mean the name of the database - like the thing that contains all small tables or they mean the exact table to which to connect. Score is the name of table containing some values.

UID is I think username for logging into the database - I used the one I use to access PHPMyAdmin. (You can use it too, It's just free database, nothing important in it)

Password - password used to log into PHPMyAdmin.

Yes, and the error, AggregateException: 192.168.100.3:3306 No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. 192.168.100.3:3306

Please help me or point me to a good tutorial. I would like to have an online SQL server. Most of tutorials are for local server - Idk, should I watch them? Is it the same as an online server? How to make the transition to online then?

Comment: first step: try to connect to the database with with this login infos from a original mysql client like : mysql -h hostname -u username -p . then the client asked for password. if this working we can look at your code

Comment: When you create the database they give you all the information required to build a connectionstring. Including the server (it is not your localhost name but remotemysql.com), the port number (3306), the database name and the credentials required to access it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the info given in your code then you should be able to connect remotely to that database with these changes

```
string server = "removemysql.com";
string database = "iqWUaqal5x";
string uid = "iqWUaqal5x";
string password = "Q4tcOaJXdW";
string connectionString;
connectionString = $"SERVER={server};PORT=3306;DATABASE={database};UID={uid};PASSWORD={password};";
```

Notice that I assume that the database name is the same as your user name. I have tried to use this service (and at first sight it seems pretty done) and the first database has the same name as the user.

**IMPORTANT**
Be sure to read [their FAQ](https://remotemysql.com/faq.html). The limitations on their service could be a problem for real applications.

Answer (score 0):

Try if that works. I believe the issue was the incorrect server name. Also, when you use Uid as user id, try to use Pwd for password.

Check out the official docs on the same : https://remotemysql.com/tutor4.html

Please edit the answer and remove if those are actual credentials.

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System;

namespace SQLTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello world"); //for testing
            string server = "remotemysql.com";
            string database = "Score";
            string uid = "xxxx";
            string password = "xxxx";
            string connectionString;
            connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + "; PORT = 3306 ;" + "DATABASE=" + database + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PWD=" + password + ";";
            MySqlConnection mycon = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
            mycon.Open(); //error
            Console.WriteLine("Connection Open  !");
            mycon.Close();
        }
    }
}
```